# How to load a Swing GUI Form using a JavaFX controller (Button in JavaFX)

Tags: swing, javafx

I want to load a Java Swing GUI form using a JavaFX controller. This should happen when the button is clicked in the JavaFX File, then the Swing GUI form should be loaded.

I tried to load a Swing GUI form using the normal way but it didn't work.

```
Example ex=new Example;
ex.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific with what you are asking? 
I ran the following code successfully.

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

            // 2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            // 3. Create components and put them in the frame.
            // ...create emptyLabel...
            frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Test"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

            // 4. Size the frame.
            frame.pack();

            // 5. Show it.
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

handleButtonAction is a function in the controller class of my JavaFX project.

Did you want to create a separate window, or embed Swing in a JavaFX Window?

Comment: @James_D I have updated the answer to add the code to the AWT event dispatch thread. Does this adequately address your concern?